# how to calculate time in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time

I have a table looks like this

```
ID              DTTM
123456789   2017-10-05 08:00:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 08:05:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 08:07:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 08:15:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 08:25:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 09:00:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 09:01:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 09:02:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 09:03:00.000
123456789   2017-10-05 11:00:00.000
```

I need to create a flag based on time interval (date isn't matter)
It has to be 15 minute interval in order to set the flag to 1
So in this case rows 1,4,6,10 will be flag and the total will be 4 for this ID
Every time if the `interval >= 15 minutes` it will start again until the next one
I've tried something like this;
With myLead AS

```
(
Select        top 100 percent 
            ID,
            DTTM,                
            LEAD(DTTM,1) over (partition by ID order by DTTM) as NextDTTM
From        Example
Order by    ID
), myCount
AS
(
Select      Top 100 percent
            ID,
            DTTM,
            NextDTTM,
            DateDiff("MINUTE",DTTM,NextDTTM) as Interval
from        myLead
)
Select      ID,
            DTTM,
            NextDTTM,
            Interval,
            Case When Interval >= 15 then 1 else 0 END as CountFlag
From        myCount
Where       Interval is not NULL
Order by    ID
```

But it not works as expected? how do I solve this.

Thanks,
Oded Dror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you need the flag to looks like, but using `SQL Server 2012` they are two tricky parts. First, to get the difference in time between next and previous row:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ID] BIGINT
   ,[DTTM] DATETIME2
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([ID], [DTTM])
VALUES   (123456789, '2017-10-05 08:00:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 08:05:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 08:07:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 08:15:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 08:25:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 09:00:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 09:01:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 09:02:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 09:03:00.000')
        ,(123456789, '2017-10-05 11:00:00.000');

SELECT *  
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CONVERT(TIME, [DTTM]),LEAD(CONVERT(TIME, [DTTM]), 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DTTM])) AS [Minutes]
FROM @DataSource
ORDER BY [DTTM];
```

[image]

Then, we need to `sum` the minutes from the begging of over interval to current row and divide them to `15`:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *  
          ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,LAG(CONVERT(TIME, [DTTM]), 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DTTM]), CONVERT(TIME, [DTTM])) AS [Minutes]
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT *
      ,SUM(ISNULL([Minutes], 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DTTM] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 15 AS [MinutesRank]
FROM DataSource;
```

[image]

Having this, you can do whatever you need, as we now how many minutes we have till each row. For example:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *  
          ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,LAG(CONVERT(TIME, [DTTM]), 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DTTM]), CONVERT(TIME, [DTTM])) AS [Minutes]
    FROM @DataSource
)
, DataSourceMinutesTotal AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,SUM(ISNULL([Minutes], 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY [DTTM] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) / 15 AS [MinutesRank]
    FROM DataSource
)
SELECT [ID], [DTTM]
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [ID] ORDER BY ISNULL([MinutesRank], 0)) AS [IntervalID]
FROM DataSourceMinutesTotal
ORDER BY [DTTM];
```

[image]

Comment: Gotqn,

Thank you for your help, the problem solved already. This solution will not give the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **MySQL** then you can try using `TIMEDIFF(param1, param2)`
* param1 and param2 can be times or datetimes values

Comment: Thank you for contacting me, the problem soled. Yours approach did not soled the issue.